# R: error in adding new column to data frame without any rows "replacement has 1 row, data has 0"

Tags: r, dataframe

I am adding a new variable local to the dataframe front_page, which is obtained using median of another variable from another data frame. Below is the code. I am ending up with with this error below.

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, local, value = 3.5) :
> replacement has 1 row, data has 0

```
front_page$local <- median(restock_duration_food_local$food_supplier_local_duration, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please, do not ever forget to include a reproducible example showing the tables that your are refering to. You can use `dput(front_page)` and `dput(restock_duration_food_local)` and include their outputs in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that your data frame is empty (data has 0 *rows*) and you're assigning a new column with one row. Please make sure you've declared data frame *front_page* correctly.